# ack-grep: command not found in gvim after upgrade to Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: vim, grep, ack

Running `:Ack anything` in gvim now gives

```
|| /bin/bash: ack-grep: command not found
```

ack-grep is already the newest version (2.22-1)

It was working fine in Ubuntu 16.04. I have the ack.vim plugin in ~/.vim/bundle/ack.vim/

Comment: what happens if you run ack-grep from the terminal?

Comment: ack-grep: command not found, but maybe that's only because I ran: sudo dpkg-divert --local --divert /usr/bin/ack --rename --add /usr/bin/ack-grep ?

Comment: You'll probably get better help over at 'ask ubuntu' now that we've established it's not really a problem with your vim setup.

Comment: They just said to use ask instead of ack-grep. I don't know how to get ack.vim working

Comment: Looks like `g:ackprg` is a var where you can select the command to run, so maybe you can point it to `ask` or whatever else might be compatible with its purpose.  The github page has an example of using the Silver Searcher with the command `ag --vimgrep`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using this [ack.vim](https://github.com/mileszs/ack.vim) plugin. Then you shouldn't have to do anything.

Ack.vim will search for executables in the following order: `ack-grep`, `ack`. You can override this with `g:ackprg`. If you have set `g:g:ackprg` then you will need to adjust `g:ackprg` to be set to where the ack executable path.

```
let g:ackprg = '/usr/local/bin/ack'
```

Personally, I would avoid setting the `g:ackprg` variable unless you really need to.

You may also want to look into faster grep program's than `ack`. e.g. [The Silver Searcher](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher) or [ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep). I also haven't really found a need for a plugin like ack.vim, I just set `'grepprg'` and `'grepformat'` and search with `:grep`.

Comment: Just installing the Silver Searcher fixed it, thanks. ack.vim just worked as before after that. ack.vim lets me search the word under the cursor with \AK which is handy. Not sure is that available with just grep.

Comment: Ripgrep/Silver searcher "star search": `nnoremap <silent> <leader>* :<c-u>execute "grep '" . expand('<cword>') . "' -w"<bar>redraw!<bar>:cc<cr>`